# What are the /dev/ramX devices?

Tags: 11.04, ram

In /dev I have 12 or so devices named ram0 ram1 etc. What are those? What can they be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lil' search, showed Those are RAM disks.

**What is a RAM disk?**

- A RAM disk is a portion of RAM which is being used as if it were a
  disk drive. RAM disks have fixed sizes, and act like regular disk
  partitions. Access time is much faster for a RAM disk than for a
  real, physical disk. However, any data stored on a RAM disk is lost
  when the system is shut down or powered off. RAM disks can be a great
  place to store temporary data.

For short,  a RAM disk is a virtual file system that runs entirely from your PC’s main memory, which means it’s lightning fast to read and write anything you want.